# Trailing slash at end of URL wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Dears,

I want to add / at the end of each url of site, below is what i found online, it works good, but in wp-admin it gives me `wp-admin/index.php/index.php/`. Like everytime i click on dashboard it will add `/index.php/`

code from htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep redirect rule before your default WP rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Make sure to use a new browser for your testing.

Comment: I am not sure about above code, it gives not found on pages when no / is added. With / it was ok.  but then i modified rule to like from my post. `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]` Now its working. And wp-admin is not giving multiple index.php. Thanks

Comment: can you explain the difference between `RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]` and the one i added. Thanks

Comment: I forgot adding `/` after `%{REQUEST_URI}` in my rule. It is edited now and should work. `%{REQUEST_URI} ` is reserved `mod_rewrite` variable, that has value of complete request uri. If your have this rule in site root .htaccess then `(.*)` after `RewriteRule` will also have value of complete request URI without leading slash.