# How to add "/" on URL end in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with my Wordpress site. I have duplicate content on my site because my Wordpress showing up pages with "/" and without "/". How can i change it to this: when on page we don't have "/" on URL end then please redirect to version with "/". E.g: if adress is www.web.com/page please redirect to www.web.com/page/ Thanks for help :)!

Comment: In case of an apache server, do you have access to the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trailing slash at end of URL wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47429153/trailing-slash-at-end-of-url-wordpress)

Comment: There are plugins that can help you set rel=lanonical tag and issue with duplicate content would be solved.

Comment: Yes, i have access to `.htaccess`. I tried info from Emile Pels but this not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings >> Permalinks >> Custom Structure
and in custom structure add "/" at the end. 
This will work

Comment: Then nothing changes. The pages with and without "/" still work.

Answer (score 1):

Right below the RewriteEngine On line in .htaccess, add

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to edit your htaccess :

Right below the RewriteEngine On line, add:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to .htaccess in the root of your site.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I added to index.php file this code. It's ok ;)

```js
if (substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], -1) != "/") {
 header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
 header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'/');
 die;
}
```